# Accessing sqlite db from Visual Foxpro vfp9

Tags: sqlite, visual-foxpro, foxpro, querying

I am using Visual Foxpro (Vfp9).
I have stored sqlite db file on my server.
I want to access it from vfp like php does.

How I can achieve this.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get and install SQLite ODBC driver if you haven't done so yet:

[SQLite ODBC driver download](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/sqliteodbc.exe)

Then it is easy. You simply use one of the techniques accessing external data (SQL pass through, Remote views, Cursor adapter). ie: With SQL Pass Through:

```
Local dbName, handle, lcSQL, ix, cSample
dbName = 'd:\temp\MyDb.s3db'
handle = Sqlstringconnect( Textmerge("driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=<< m.dbName >>") )

SQLExec(m.handle, "create table mySampleTable (id int primary key, dummy varchar(50))")

TEXT to lcSQL noshow
insert into mySampleTable
  (id, dummy)
values
  (?m.ix, ?m.cSample)
ENDTEXT

For ix = 1 To 10
    cSample = 'Dummy no ' + Ltrim(Str(m.ix))
    SQLExec(m.handle, m.lcSQL)
Endfor

SQLExec(m.handle, 'select * from mySampleTable','sample')
SQLDisconnect(0)

Select Sample
Browse
```

Note: Normally when inserting in a loop, you would use SQLPrepare() and transaction for performance. I didn't care about that here.

Comment: i have sqlite db on server. i want to connect that file. For local database it is working.I want to connect servers sqlite db file.thanks.

Comment: what we do like with php and mysql connectivity.I have php code which connect to sqlite db stored on my hosting server (domain name).

Comment: means i want to connect sqlite stored on server from vfp9 like pho does.

Comment: You need to read documentation about SQLite. SQLite is file based and not a server technology. You say like PHP does, as if you don't know that also php is a serverside technology. It has no similarity to mySQL connection which is client server. SQLite is not client server. If you create a server side VFP script say in IIS then you can access SQLite like php does (check foxisapi and other tools on the internet).